# Is there a way to specify the size of an image in the resource file?

Tags: codenameone

If I create a radio button, the size of the circle matches the size of the font. So if I'm running on a tablet, where it uses a bigger font, I also get a bigger radio button circle and dot. But if I use an image from the resource file, it chooses the image to create something in the exact same size, regardless of the platform, as far as I can tell. So my radio button image is the same size as the font on a smaller platform, but it's smaller than the font on a tablet. In some cases this is may be the desired behavior, but at other times it's not. My image is scaled to every possible resolution in my reference file, so it should be able to produce a fine image at a larger size. I just don't see a way to specify that.

Answer (score 1):

A multi-image would probably do what you need. It's really multiple images in one, you load different image sizes for different screen resolutions, and the proper one is shown for each device.

Comment: FYI a radio button/checkbox uses the `FontImage` class and specifically the `MATERIAL_*` entries within for the icon. You can set them as icons and they also auto-adapt to color scheme changes in the buttons  see: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/material-icons-background-music-geofencing-gradle.html http://www.codenameone.com/blog/pressed-selected-icon-font-utf-8.html

Comment: Actually, I was talking about multi-images. On a iPhone, they show up in the right size, but on a tablet, which uses a larger font, the show up too small. It would be nice if I knew a way to scale it for the font size. (There are so many options for scaling in the resource editor that there may be one that I missed, but the one I tried didn't work.)

Comment: BTW, I tried the MultiImage, but I got another curious result, which maybe should be filed as a separate issue. I created two .png files (selected and unselected), and added them as multi-images in the resource editor. It drew my icons as it should, but it drew the standard black circle on top of my image. So it didn't actually replace the standard image with mine.

Comment: The suggestion to use Material icons looked useful, but it still has a problem. The example uses a toggle button, but the same icon is drawn for both selected and unselected. So clicking the button doesn't change its appearance. I don't see a way to specify different icons for selected and unselected.

Comment: I also tried this:

  Button unselected = CheckBox.createToggle("Unselected");

  final Style unselectedStyle = unselected.getUnselectedStyle();

  unselectedStyle.setBgImage(FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_THUMB_UP, unselectedStyle));

  Style selectedStyle = unselected.getSelectedStyle();

  selectedStyle.setBgImage(FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_THUMB_DOWN, selectedStyle), true);

This didn't work either.

Comment: Also, I haven't tried this, but in stepping through the code, it doesn't look like I can write my own Painter to paint the RadioButton.

Comment: `MultiImage` works based on device density so a UI on a tablet won't appear like a blown up phone and actually uses the extra space for more information. So the font shouldn't be larger based on that philosophy. If you are building a game and want to treat density/multi image based on resolution there are samples of that in the Pocker/solitaire demos. For font image use FontImage.setIcon() which will implicitly set everything correctly with the pressed/released colors.

Comment: I'm not building a game. Multi-images do a great job of solving the problem of multiple resolutions, but that's not the issue I'm raising here. You said "the font shouldn't be larger based on that philosophy," but the fonts **are** larger on tablets than on mobile phones. So if I use a multi-image for a radio button, it looks fine with a small font on a phone, but it's too small for the larger tablet font. Sometimes I don't want the image to scale to the larger device and other times I do. Multi-images only solve one of those problems.

Comment: I should add that sometimes I want the icon to scale to the font, and other times I want it to scale up for the larger screen. I don't know how you implemented the default radio buttons, but if they're done with FontImage, it should be possible to write a FontImage icon class that adjusts to a component's foreground color. That might bypass the problem of scaling to a larger font. (I would still want to scale to the screen.)